# How to boot persisted Ubuntu image?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I am using Ubuntu 14.4 on Live USB, here i have installed and configured my project work. But now i am planning to permanently install the same on my system.
Is there a way to install the entire persisted image, i mean the exact copy of Live USB permanently onto my system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you precisely mean by exact copy of Live USB? @ranjzz

Comment: @spharish I mean i have installed some applications and configured project on my Persistent linux OS on USB, can i boot this onto system without losing data? i mean not a fresh copy of the OS, but OS with the installed softwares and data.

Answer (score -1):

If your looking to install the Ubuntu OS, a great tutorial (depending on your Windows) would be  [here](http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/). Your question was unclear to me, so maybe you just want to copy your work to Windows from the portable boot. Just simply copy the file into the folder "Windows" on the file explorer.

Comment: I use persistent ubuntu live USB, i installed some applications and have done some configurations too(all on USB). But now i want to install the OS permanently onto my system without losing data, i mean installed apps and others need to be intact, i dont need a fresh copy of the OS.